# Deriving object type from array of objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given this type:

```
type ItemMetadata = {
    name: string;
    valueType: "string" | "number" | "boolean";
};
```

I want to construct an array of parameters

```
const MyMetaDatas = [
    {
        name: "The String",
        valueType: "string"
    },
    {
        name: "The Number",
        valueType: "number"
    }
] as const satisfies readonly ItemMetadata[];
```

And given this - readonly MyMetaDatas array, I would like to consturct an object which looks like this

```
const MyParameters = {
   "The String": "string",
   "The Number": "number"
}
```

And I want to "type" this object type as a generic with 1 parameter - `typeof MyMetadatas` - e.g. `ParametersFor<T extends readonly ItemMetadata[]> = { ...TODO }`

**Attempt #1**

```
/**
 * Attempt on generating { name: valueType } map object, from const array of ItemMetadata
 */
type ItemParameters<T extends readonly ItemMetadata[]> = {
    [K in T[number]["name"]]: T[number]["valueType"];
};
/**
 * Not nice because T[number]["valueType"] looks at all of the items in the array
type MyParams = {
  "The String": "string" | "number" | "boolean";
  "The Number": "string" | "number" | "boolean";
}
 */
type MyParams = ItemParameters<typeof MyMetaDatas>;
```

This does procudce the left side of the object correctly, but `T[number]` at the right side looks at the all of the items in the array, it produces OR types of all of the options...

**Attempt #2**
Tried multiple things, came up with this. This does not produce object, it produces a tuple of ojbects, where there is only one key - [name], and one value - [valueType].

```
type ParamsUsingSingle<T extends readonly ItemMetadata[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        [TName in T[K]["name"]]: T[K]["valueType"];
    }
};
type MyParamsUsingSingle = ParamsUsingSingle<typeof MyMetaDatas>;
/**
 * Close but now I would have to merge them into a signle object somehow.. Or to Flatten
 */
const x: MyParamsUsingSingle = [
    {
        "The String": "string"
    },
    {
        "The Number": "number",
    }
]
```

But now I need to merge them somehow...

Can anyone help me with this task?

Here are my numberous attempts in [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/PQKhCgAIUh7AjAVgUwMYBdKtgOwM4CWe6BOA5nAGaQ4CGAtspLTgCbOQButANgK5N0ATwAOyKCGDhhYyAEl0yegFlk6Wq1rrIAXkgBvKJGN1GALkjEATqTIBuI8e79kAFVHILAImu2vkAB9ILxw%20enhkK38gr3hYWB5kFi8HAF8HUAhoSGUhSCsk1lwePNorK1o82GoFJVV1TXUJKWx8TFz62gARLVo8XUgAbUcDEeMTBk9g1wALJgBldBtyLwAaMfHnAXcxb18VkdT18dGTk9Mpr1mmADkwiKjjs6debY9vUPDIr0On40NnhNzNM5pAAELxRLJP5nLZud7BOIJJI4H4nI4jAGAi7ea6QRbLMgAJjWGxeLh2l32ZDR41S4AAusx%20q1iJYtERKARkP0Chpinlaio1BpeoMGQ5wFLMhJIABBdCKegiTC4SBkZA4SIc8gGGiTCxwymQVKQei0ERwJBodCrSCUKywehYXBssoVKo1JWdRq0ZrSDzyJUABTKk0UVjwAB5XJBkAAPRRsXmFAVBuoi33igB8AyxxkGAGlIKRIK5Bp8HgzBiFJl4GQyLOXK5Fq14jR562kMmBZTdYJgcARUEwIqhaHw8Exm-dWzWO2J65AePEANb9LTMHg8KiQdCgghK-ql-dMd2VAOyXKhir0fp6LFXUEEvx7JZ%20QLBFtRT%20xSEolIjCfW5ZyiN9CWiL9QMgv9kWSBxjGA8F-2ScCPxib8YKRKFUQQkEFnfcgSTQlZf0w39sIAtJ-RkJhrzDO8BiFG9w0iaNaOqHIhE6Hp1DwbNJRlbIFSVFUuCJSAaMDZiGLUNiRKUFUiRjONE01VgU35HASnTYUGjFBlcwfEYixLHBIFXZAhE41xGzLIs2wXZAu3AdJpV7bJ9yISBEEnTBUD5RR%20nQPgRESXcnP6MEAFVY1PAgrC4V4eWYTBT0gERYEIEhXWYAoXXKG0AEJZVoriWLvBTlXQCS9D5IptLyGtqTWKCvkeREUNRO0fEImkGSkq8hAqvAqqUpiQ1kiNRsVRSaqjDjqA6EVeL6AT3KyGAxswTgAGZIAAWjgRr7VgRLCHIcKhUGpgZNvOSrBUhMkw03SfV6IzTiGYtS3LWtGHrOy-qclz6SEmAulgFKREdVg%20BHSwnTUGZbHyJI8FwWh4ESO14D4VUTsoM7IAARksMRUAILlUBLJV-XBvdA1yeZbESYNbwABjzEYkJfFYSJpajoCkMrmdZ5B2YYLm9Du1jHsWrieN6PBBg5wzwAZ0WhBZy6JdvMnjJOJC7narwPmgoXJEvOjtfFyX6AN3SKoehaPE45b1FWlWSfVzWmdt3X7dqr7ELxCE4NRbxKPg1ybq4nWyDZ29g9lxgI1dsR3e4lblcGIl1a1hOk4YfaZcm%20704Vj3ulz3b1Y1jyYDBfG404TU9ysIRUfQWAsECs9ykqXdTynOORuii6yCL5AnrU5M0a0nShXe9Qc25k5TNLSzrOoWyLFTl3y0LdW3K18fJ%20ngZz9saeM%20QLOlb49aGYAYRXKdIDx2091BQgyDoEK%20UVywHXJAPgichB2hYOwHAsAADu8hIBwNgHwHg7AZi0DbnuXujArAah-koMyPcrQoAwIjRgMx4EADoqH%20lZJgeMFh6K3jwBPG%204sBjDBOPmM4vM%20pm2CC1X4mIyT4UgCbB4AiQjQRhBibhoikLhxwlI6O3VhHyMBGIvmxIpFCPRIyIAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right direction with your first attempt, however, you shouldn't just write `T[number]['valueType']`, since it will give a union of all possibilities. Instead, you should use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type GetParameters<T extends readonly ItemMetadata[]> = {
  [K in T[number] as K["name"]]: K["valueType"];
};
```

Usage:

```
// type Params = {
//     "The String": "string";
//     "The Number": "number";
// }
type Params  = GetParameters<typeof MyMetaDatas>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4&ssl=17&ssc=52&pln=17&pc=53#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsCyFgEMAmb1QLxQG8AoKKAOzQQgC4oBnYAJwEsyBzAbhKgDc0AbAK4QAKuBpQARAxbtJUAD5SyghACMIjeUslqA9nv4Q0ZSVwC+XIgGM9ZBlCQgU6ACLY0dPFADa3YqSkFFS0kiIAFtAAykysbJIANNykfEKi4qEycYnc5kmkAYHBEmGRUAByqhpa+YGpwmKQoSrqmjmkeUQAulCeULb2wPTYzHQAZswQXozGGHb8ILDwyKiYHj5dVqCQUADiqAAKaIyUqJp0ADwiUBAAHvBkGNOz84twiC5r6BsAfN6FPgA0lBWFARD4WtUen1AT5JMVJF0urRYZJ6ulIIiLFYAPQ4qDbaBHE4ILz4Yh4wKkUrRWJyTJ0+JcSlUmkVKptZocrTM-HmIiEqDEyhebz7YDCqjwRiXQl6MaOZyrdzoOg-IA)

Comment: Marvelous! I did try that `as` keyword, but got it wrong, and started to look at other directions.